# fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' running build via vcvarsall.bat x86

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I am trying to build 32bit exe on 64bit OS.
Steps that I followed :

1. I ran Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) which sets environment for
   x86 tools.(as admin) also tried "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
   Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86**"
2. I ran the makefile.nt via nmake.
3. I am using boost Libraries which are 32 bit .
4. Ran into error

> "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_50.lib(thread.obj) : fatal error LNK1112:
>   module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'"

I understand my OS is 64bit and my target machine is X86 but this problem should be taken care when I trigger `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86` which automatically sets environment variable for x86.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Boost library you link with isn't built for a 32-bit target. You need to install a specific 32-bit build of Boost and use that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I checked lib file via dumpbin /headers *.lib | findstr machine it returned x86 Machine .

Comment: Well that is what the error is saying, that the "module" (library) is built for 64-bit targets. Do you have multiple installations of Boost? Are you using the right one in your build?

Comment: I just checked. I using one instance of boost lib and yes I am using right one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for input.After debugging for two days. I found that I have multiple installations of boost library included in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for input.After debugging for two days. I found that I have multiple installations of boost library included in my solution